# Coordinates of a vector in a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to check my calculations for a problem I'm working on.

Let $\alpha=(0,i-1,i+1)$ be a vector $W$.

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}=\{(1,0,i),(1+i,1,-1)\}$ be a basis for a vector space $W$.

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{\beta_1,\beta_2\}=\{(1,1,0),(1,i,1+i)\}$ be another basis for a vector space $W$.

(a)  Let $[\alpha]_\mathcal{A}$ and $[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}$ be the coordinates of $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ respectively.

This I calculated as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix}0\\i-1\\i+1\end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\i\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$

Which yields:

$[\alpha]_\mathcal{A}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\i-1\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}0\\i-1\\i+1\end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\\1+i\end{pmatrix}$

Which yields:
$[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$

(b)  Find a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $U[\alpha]_\mathcal{A}=[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}$

I'm assuming that this wants us to consider the following:

$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\i\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\\1+i\end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\i\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$

This yields transition matrix:

$U=\begin{pmatrix}-i & 2-i\\1 &i\end{pmatrix}.$

However I tested the above matrix and yielded $U[\alpha]_\mathcal{A}\neq[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this backwards.  Since I want to move from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ I need to be computing a matrix $U$ as follows $\alpha_1=c_1\beta_1+c_2\beta_2$ and $\alpha_2=d_1\beta_1+d_2\beta_2$.  Then my $U=\begin{bmatrix}c_1 & d_1\\c_2 & d_2\end{bmatrix}$