# Finding the matrix representation for a linear transformation and using it to evaluate $[T(\alpha)]_\mathcal{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A lot of this falls back on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688272/coordinates-of-a-vector-in-a-different-basis).  But I will state the details here again.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$.  Suppose that $\mathcal{A}=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $\mathcal{B}=(\beta_1,\beta_2)$ both form an ordered basis for $W$.  Let $\alpha=(0,i-1,i+1)$ be a vector in $W$.

Let $T: W \to W$ be the linear transformation $T(x_1\alpha_1+x_2\alpha_2)=(x_1-x_2)\alpha_1+(x_1+x_2)\alpha_2.$  Find the matrix representaiton ${}_{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{\mathcal{A}}$ and use it to find $T[(\alpha)]_\mathcal{B}$.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem.  There are a few things bugging me about the notation  The ${}_{\mathcal{B}}[T]_\mathcal{A}$ is giving me the impression that we are taking $[\alpha]_\mathcal{B}$ and then feeding it into $[T(\alpha)]_\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: What's the "prescript" bit about?  Are you trying to write $_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A}$?

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't feel like writing a full answer, but the main idea is that the subscript on the right denotes the basis of the input, and the subscript on the left denotes the basis of the output.  That is,
$$
{}_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A} [x]_{\mathcal A} = [T(x)]_{\mathcal B}
$$

Comment: But, won't the output be w.r.t $\mathcal{B}$ but being multiplied by the basis elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Ultimately I'm not sure how to calculate ${}_\mathcal{B}[T]_\mathcal{A}$ and its relationship to $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice approach: note that the first column of the matrix ${}_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A}$ is given by
$$
{}_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A} \pmatrix{1\\0} = [T(1 \cdot \alpha_1 + 0 \cdot \alpha_2)]_{\mathcal B} = [\alpha_1 + \alpha_2]_{\mathcal B} = \\
[(1,0,i) + (1+i,1,-1)]_{\mathcal B}  = [(2 + i,1,-1 + i)]_{\mathcal B} \\
[\color{red}{2} \cdot (1,1,0) + \color{red}{i}\cdot (1,i,1+i)]_{\mathcal B} = \\
[\color{red}{2} \cdot  \beta_1 + \color{red}{i}\cdot  \beta_2]_{\mathcal B} =\pmatrix{2 \\ i}
$$
The coefficients $2,i$ either had to be calculated by solving the system 
$$
c_1 \cdot (1,1,0) + c_2 \cdot (1,i,1+i) = (2 + i,1,-1 + i)
$$
for coefficients $c_1,c_2$, or could also be calculated using the transition matrix $U$ which you were meant to compute in the previous question.

All together, we now know that
$$
{}_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A} = \pmatrix{2 & ?\\i & ?}
$$
You can calculate the second column similarly by computing ${}_{\mathcal B}[T]_{\mathcal A} \pmatrix{0\\1}$ in the method outlined above.

Comment: Then would $[T(\alpha)]_{\mathcal(B)}={}_{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{\mathcal{A}}[\alpha]_{\mathcal{A}}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right